# How can I create a Textbox which only accepts certain integer values?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I've searched the web and was unable to find what I am looking for. I'm using VS2010 and trying to make a w7p app. I'm trying to make a textbox that only accepts a single integer value from 0 to 5, so no negative and no decimal as any value higher crashes the app. Thank you!

Comment: http://www.atleyhunter.com/2010/11/12/making-textbox-numbers-only-for-windows-phone-7/

Comment: i found this on my own but i need to restrict it to a single int value, so the only accpeted values would be {0,1,2,3,4,5} , so that 10 wont work

Comment: pity you didn't mention that in your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `NumericUpDown` control, if there is one and you can just set the `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties.

If there's not, use this in the `KeyDown` event of the textbox:

```
List<Keys> allowedKeys = new List<Keys>()
{
    Keys.Back, Keys.D0, Keys.D1, Keys.D2, Keys.D3, Keys.D4, Keys.D5,
    Keys.NumPad0, Keys.NumPad1, Keys.NumPad2, Keys.NumPad3, Keys.NumPad4, Keys.NumPad5
};

e.SuppressKeyPress = !allowedKeys.Contains(e.KeyCode);
```

This will suppress anything that is not a `0-5` or `BACKSPACE` key. Also, set your `Maximum Length` property to `1`, it will allow *only* 0 through 5.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the change event of the textbox and check its value using regex (or parse it as an integer and compare it with you range).

Comment: regexp for this is a bad idea

Comment: @Sylverdrag: I guess the phone has limited resources in memory and CPU cycles so you don't want to fire a regex at it on every keypress.

Comment: @ChrisWue: I am not sure how much resources it would use, but assuming it's too much, that makes sense.

Comment: @Selverdrag just an overkill all around.  You almost never *really* need a regexp for anything, especially something as simple as checking a number range.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion thou I looked into it and i may be able to use this for something in the future

Comment: @MK: Sure. "Regex.Match("[0-5]").Success" is such an overkill, not to mention unreadable and hard to understand compared to a simple solution like restricting the keys and capturing only the keys you want. I can understand that on mobile, resources are scarce and going for other solutions might be justified (I don't know how much overhead is required by the Regex library). On desktop however, that overhead is insignificant and Regex can simplify things considerably.